# How to make my docker run on a specified linux kernel version?

Tags: linux, docker, centos

I'm doing trouble shooting on a rhel 6.8 version with kernel of 2.6.32. I tried docker pull centos:6.8 and it works to start, but "cat /proc/version" seems to print that the docker kernel is 4.9.2.

Seems no matter which linux images I download(centos, ubuntu), the /proc/version is the same one, as defined by docker, right?

But my requirement is to run and test some programs that is having system-level problem based on 2.6.32, I wish to do some performance test on 2.6.32. Does docker support me to switch linux kernel version? I need to clarify first if I can do it with docker, or I should turn back to traditional vm software.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply check the output of uname. the kernel version is not modified by the containers since containers and Host share the kernel.

`uname --kernel-release`